# REST API уведомления с сервера

Tags: rest

Есть клиент, который по REST запрашивает у сервера выполнение неких вычислений, растянутых во времени (несколько часов). Сервер должен предоставлять клиенту информацию о промежуточных результатах вычислений, а в конце выдать полные данные. Например, каждые несколько секунд сервер генерирует рандомное число.

Какие существуют способы реализации передачи уведомлений от REST сервера к клиенту?

Comment: На каком языке программирования вы хотите делать REST API?

Comment: C#. Это не существенно

Comment: Long pooling, webhooks - советую смотреть в эту сторону

Comment: Но вообще клиент то может и отвалиться в процессе выполнения работы на сервере. Так что хорошо бы выполняемой задаче дать некий id и накапливать на сервере промежуточные данные по нему. А клиент может обратиться отдельным запросом для получения этих данных по id задачи (а возможно, вообще обойтись без долго висящих соединений, а периодически запрашивать нет ли новых данных)

Answer (score 0):

Long pooling или SSE (Server-Sent Events) - то что вам надо.
 Не думаю что веб сокеты то что вам подойдет